# QTablewidget : How to get inserted Picture from certain (Row,Col)

Tags: c++, image, qt, qtablewidget

I've inserted a picture to a table.

```
    QTableWidgetItem *template_to_insert = new QTableWidgetItem();
    template_to_insert->setData(Qt::DecorationRole, QPixmap::fromImage(templ_));
    ui->tableWidget_2->insertRow(ui->tableWidget_2->rowCount());
    ui->tableWidget_2->setItem(0, 0, template_to_insert);
```

Now I want to select the inserted picture and move it to another table.

My try:

```
    QTableWidgetItem * item = ui->tableWidget->item(0, 0);
    ui->tableWidget_3->insertRow(ui->tableWidget_2->rowCount());
    ui->tableWidget_3->setItem(ui->tableWidget_2->rowCount()-1, 0, item);
```

But I insert an empty row to the target.
Can you maybe explain me my mistake ? Or can you maybe show me an example how to do it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found my mistake.
Instead of **item()** I have to use **takeitem()**.

Solution:

```
    QTableWidgetItem * item = ui->tableWidget->takeitem(0, 0);
    ui->tableWidget_3->insertRow(ui->tableWidget_2->rowCount());
    ui->tableWidget_3->setItem(ui->tableWidget_2->rowCount()-1, 0, item);
```